# how to connect sql and asp.net

Tags: asp.net

am running the asp.net application...am enhancing the already developed project..i want to create the horizontal menus through which i should get the menu items from the database so that if any changes i have to made in future i can update in database alone not in the application,,,i dont know how to give link and where to code for this...someone help me out...how to connect the database and the asp.net application...thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the link

[Connect to SQL Server Using SQL Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The first:
In database you create table menu
in table menu have 4 colums
1. ID int identity primary key,
2. Name(50) not null,
3. Images(200),
4. Description (100),
The second:
You have connect string.
if you don't know connect string you google with keyword "connect string" and go to box "SQL Server" and then put out connect string.
.Often connect their string in the file declarations global.asax
And then in file website you created or datalist and gridview to collect data from sql server.