# Sending data with asp to stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

How would I send data from ASP.NET to a stored procedure?

I want to be able to take data from my form and then send it to my ASP.NET (I know how to do this), then I want to use that information with the ASP.NET in a stored procedure that will update a row in my table.

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow before asking? Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775904/how-to-connect-sql-and-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an sample code to connect an stored procedure using ADO.NET

```
static string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();
dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SpUpdateUser", dbConnection);
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = age;
dbConnection.Open();
dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbConnection.Close();
```

Here username and age are passed to the stored procedure `SpUpdateUser`, which expects two input arguments `@UserName` and `@Age`.